# reduce duplicate code in wordpress

Tags: theme-development

// I have this code in my single.php file and i am trying to reduce duplication
//  code is under below, this code works for me but this is displaying multiple //messages to me such as 
/*
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-5.3.2\wp-content\themes\personal\functions.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: subtitle in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-5.3.2\wp-content\themes\personal\functions.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: photo in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-5.3.2\wp-content\themes\personal\functions.php on line 10 
*/

```
// SINGLE.PHP File
while (have_posts() ) {
    the_post();   
  site_banner_section();
  ?>
```

// FUNCTIONS.PHP File

```
<?php

function site_banner_section($args = null) {
  if (!$args['title']) {
    $args['title'] = get_the_title();
  }
  if (!$args['subtitle']) {
    $args['subtitle'] = get_field('page_banner_subtitle');
  }
  if (!$args['photo']) {
    if (get_field('page_banner_background_image')) {
      $args['photo']= get_field('page_banner_background_image')['sizes']['bannerImage'];
    }else{
      $args['photo']=get_theme_file_uri('/images/ocean.jpg');
    }
  }
  ?>
  <div class="page-banner">
  <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $args['photo']; ?>);"></div>
  <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
    <h1 class="page-banner__title"><?php echo $args['title']; ?></h1>
    <div class="page-banner__intro">
      <p><?php echo $args['subtitle']; ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function site_banner_section($args = null) {
    if (!$args['title']) {
```

You're getting warnings from these lines

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-5.3.2\wp-content\themes\personal\functions.php on line 4
>   Notice: Undefined index: subtitle in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-5.3.2\wp-content\themes\personal\functions.php on line 7

because $args might be null and you're still trying to treat it as an array, and because you're trying to access properties that may or may not exist to check their existence, which may work in other languages but isn't how you're meant to do this in PHP. You probably want something like:

```
function site_banner_section( $args = null ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $args ) ) {
        $args = array();
    }
    if ( ! ( array_key_exists( 'title', $args ) && $args['title'] ) ) {
        $args['title'] = get_the_title();
```

to both make sure that $args is an array before we start testing properties on it and setting properties in it, and to check whether 'title' exists before we try and check if it's non-empty. Or if you're unlikely to be passed null as an argument, only the default, then you could use

```
function site_banner_section( $args = array() ) {
    if ( ! ( array_key_exists( 'title', $args ) && $args['title'] ) ) {
```

And I'm not sure what you meant by duplicated code. If you meant avoid having to repeatedly check whether properties exist then you could use [wp_parse_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_args/) to fill in the defaults, e.g.

```
function site_banner_section( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        // etc.
    );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
```

but then you would need to call get_the_title and get_field to populate $defaults even when you don't actually use the values.

Comment: OMG, instead of `$args = NULL` I provided `$args = array()` and instead of writing `if (!$args['title']) {
    $args['title'] = get_the_title();` I changed to `if (! ( array_key_exists( 'title', $args ) && $args['title'] )) {
    $args['title'] = get_the_title();
  }`

Comment: above code, and magically I could not see error message anymore. Thank you so much for a big help. I do not know, the above changes I made is correct way to write a code or not, I am not really strong in PHP, but I just tried and it works for me. Just a small following question, How can I find these solutions from WordPress official documentations. There is so much to learn, Things get messy for me really quick, If you can give me some guidance's then I will really appreciate. Again, huge thanks, thumbs up!

Comment: Glad it helped. Sorry, I don't know the documentation well so I don't know what to suggest but these are PHP things not specific WordPress things.

Comment: Sorry I missed your question about PHP. Obviously you're working in PHP so you'll need to read and write it to some extent, but I'm not an expert myself by any means. You can probably get by by copying patterns from existing code (I mostly do). But it wouldn't hurt to study it I suppose.

Comment: thanks, appreciate your time :)